# Verilog ams: get a value of a parameter in another module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I got an issue.
I want to get a value from a parameter in another module like this:

```
module FS0b (in2,in2,out1);
    input in1,in2;
    output out1;    
    parameter real res=10000;
endmodule 

module FS1b (in1,in2,out1);
    input in1,in2;
    output out1;

    wreal in1;
    wreal in2;
    wreal out1;

    out1=res- in1+in2;
endmodule
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, verilog parameters are applied to the instance. So you need to call parameters from the instance.

Here's your first module

```
module FS0b (in2,in2,out1);
    input in1,in2;
    output out1;

    parameter real res=10000;

endmodule
```

Let's add  a dummy parameter to the second module

```
module FS1b (in1,in2,out1);

parameter real res=10000;
    input in1,in2;
    output out1;

    wreal in1;
    wreal in2;
    wreal out1;


    assign out1=res- in1+in2;

endmodule
```

And instantiate these in top module

```
module Topmodule(...);

    FS0b fs0b{...};

    defparam
    fs1b.res = fs0b.res;
    FS1b fs1b{...};

endmodule
```

But a better application would be to define the parameter in the top module and then apply it to the hierarchy:

```
module Topmodule(...);
    parameter real res=10000;  

    defparam
    fs0b.res = res;
    FS0b fs0b{...};


    defparam
    fs1b.res = res;
    FS1b fs1b{...};

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter in verilog has local scope. It is local to the module it is defined in.

You can access the parameter from other modules using hierarchical notation however it is not at all recommended to do.

Instead you can use `define in verilog or a package in system verilog to make it global.

```
module FS0b (in1,in2,out1);
    input in1,in2;
    output out1
    parameter real res=10000;
endmodule 

module FS1b (in1,in2,out1);
    input in1,in2;
    output out1;
    wire in1;
    wire in2;
    wire out1;
    assign out1= FS0b.res - in1+in2;
endmodule
```